# After Summing Amounts Getting 'Converting circular structure to JSON' Error in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB backend I am running a `count` how many customers exist, and then saving that in a variable "totalCustomers" to pass along as part of an endpoint response:

```
let totalCustomers = await db.collection('view_customer_data').find(search).count({ $sum: "customer._id" });
```

The above is what I use when I want to count the instances, i.e., in this case, how many customers there are.

My question is around how I can use `$sum` to add up numerical values and pass that value along with the response. I tried this, but it produces a "Converting circular structure to JSON" error:

```
  let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_customer_data').find({
    "_id": { $sum: "$openBalance" }
  });
```

I also tried this:

```
  let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_customer_data').aggregate({
    "_id": { $sum: "$openBalance" }
  });
```

... and this:

```
let totalOpenBalance = await db.collection('view_customer_data').aggregate({ $group: { _id: '_id', $sum: "$openBalance"  } });
```

... but got the same error.

What should the syntax look like here?

This is for data that looks something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "44sd44444sdsd44444dsd44"), 
    }, 
    "customer" : {
        "_id" : "4th17d43561f0613be0a454f", 
        "name" : {
            "first" : "John", 
            "last" : "Smith"
        }
    }, 
    "openBalance" : 28, 
    "lastTransactionDate" : ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

The part of my function where I return the results looks like this:

```
    // preceeeding code...
    db.collection('view_customer_data').find(search).skip(skip).limit(pagesize).forEach(function (doc) {
        counter ++; {
      console.log('doc: ', doc);
      docs.push(doc);
    }

    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            if (!ioOnly) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res(err);
            }
        }
        if (ioOnly) {
            res({ sessionId: sessID, count: count, data: docs, totalCustomers: totalCustomers, totalOpenBalance: totalOpenBalance });
        }
        else {
            res.send({ count: count, data: docs, totalCustomers: totalCustomers, totalOpenBalance: totalOpenBalance });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `await db.collection('view_customer_data').aggregate(...).toArray();`. You need [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) ( or some other cursor iteration ) otherwise the result is simply a "cursor".